# Parsing formatted date with moment js

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm formatting incoming date `2016-11-10T21:59:53.000+0000` with help moment js as:

```
  myService.getDate(id)
       .then(function (data) {
           data.occuredDate = moment.utc(new Date(data.occuredDate)).format('DD MMM YYYY h:mm a');
       };
```

the output result looks like: `10 Nov 2016 10:00 pm`

Now I'm trying to parse this date back to string, but unfortunately my attempts are unsuccessful

```
  console.log(new Date(obj.occuredDate))
  console.log(new Date(obj.occuredDate).toString())
  console.log(Date.parse(obj.occuredDate))
  console.log(new Date(Date.parse(obj.occuredDate)))
  console.log(new Date(Date.parse(obj.occuredDate)).toString())

  Invalid Date
  Invalid Date
  NaN
  Invalid Date
  Invalid Date
```

Could anybody explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the initial value of `data.occuredDate`?

Comment: @Hackerman please check updated post

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ko86461s/

Comment: @Hackerman nice trick to set value to beginning value, simplicity is perfect

Comment: Yeah...you don't need to parse it back...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are parsing a non standard format, simply specify the format. Then  use moment's `toDate()` method to get a plain js Date object:

```
moment.utc(obj.occuredDate, 'DD MMM YYYY h:mm a').toDate();
```

SIDENODE

Using `moment.utc(new Date(data.occuredDate))` doesn't really make sense. Just parse the string.